# How to properly catch and add information to errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, exception

I want to add information to an Error object in typescript/javascript. I currently do it like this:

```
try {
    // code that might throw code
} catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Error while processing file ${path}:\n${e}`);
}
```

But that removes the information from the previous error.
Java/PHP both have a `previous` parameter in exceptions so I can wrap the error and preserve/extend the original information but I can't seem to find an equivalent in JavaScript.

How would I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(new Error().stack)`?

Comment: in catch you could do `let error = new Error(...etc...); error.previous = e; throw error;`

Comment: Extend the Error class and make a custom error just how you want it.

Comment: Those solutions are custom. I'm searching for a standard best practice. Adding properties to the error won't make chrome/node/deno debug tools understand it.

Comment: there is no built-in solution https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

one more option is to copy `stack` property of the original error to the newly created

Answer (score 0):

So there is no standard way.

However, if your intention is just to add information to the exception message, without messing with the error itself, you can just extend the `message` property

```
try {
} catch (e) {
    e.message = `File: ${path}\n${e.message}`;
    throw e;
}
```

This will preserve the proper stack trace and will display like you expect in chrome or on the node console.

Here an example exception:

```
Error: File: 6ff6255b-45b5-4895-8d59-50fa60663cfc.json
JSON Schema: schemas/schema.json
- must NOT have additional properties 
    at JsonFs.validate (driver/json-fs.ts:60:19)
    at JsonFs.readSource (driver/json-fs.ts:39:14)
    at async JsonFs.readSourceFile (driver/abstract-fs.ts:82:30)
    at async driver/abstract-fs.ts:46:34
```